# AWS CloudWatch GetMetricStatistics returns 0 datapoints

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am aiming to pull some metrics from a specific instance however it seems that everytime I set up the request the response will always return 0 data points.

I am setting up the request like so

```
public object GetMetric(string metricName, string instanceId)
    {
        var dimension = new Dimension
        {
            Name = "InstanceId",
            Value = instanceId
        };

        var getMetricRequest = new GetMetricStatisticsRequest
        {
            Dimensions = new List<Dimension>() { dimension },
            EndTime = DateTime.Today,
            MetricName = metricName,
            Namespace = "AWS/EC2",
            Period = (int)TimeSpan.FromDays(1).TotalSeconds,
            StartTime = DateTime.Today.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(7)),
            Statistics = new List<string> { "Maximum" },
            Unit = StandardUnit.Percent
        };

        var getMetricResponse = client2.GetMetricStatistics(getMetricRequest);
        return getMetricResponse; 
    }
```

Where `instanceId` is set to my relative instance Id and `metricName` is set to CPUUtilization. I am running a powershell script on the instance to generate small cpu spikes so I know the data is there.

According to the documentation the properties on the request are valid 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/Index.html

Am I missing something obvious? I don't understand how I am not getting any data back. I double checked the parameters and they are also correct.

EDIT: [image]

Comment: Some sanity checks: Can you show us how you're initializing the client? Also, what the response looks like?  Are you sure that the credentials you have supplied to the client have sufficient permissions to perform this action?

Comment: `AmazonCloudWatchClient client2 = new AmazonCloudWatchClient();` I will add a screenshot of the response to the question now, and I just double checked the credentials have sufficient privileges.

Comment: Is the correct region (matching the region that your ec2 instance belongs to) being specified in your client config?

Comment: I set the key for the EC2 client as `<add key="AWSRegion" value="eu-west-1"/>` in the config. Does it differ for cloudwatch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am getting datapoints now. I guess it just takes a while to send statistics to Cloud Watch.